# Передача значения поля EditText из Activity, обработка в Java класс и возврат строковой переменной обратно в Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, мобильная-разработка

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть Activity  с полем вода текста, мне надо чтобы значения данной строки передалось в Java класс без открытия новой activity (поэтому *startActivityForResult мне не подходит*), в Java классе произошла обработка и обработанное строковое значение вернулось обратно в Activity. Как это можно реализовать? 
P.S. ниже код мне надо после нажатия на кнопку переменную this.key отправить класс Obrabotchic_klucha и вернуть её обратно в Activity уже измененую

```
public void button4 (View view){
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case(R.id.imageButton2):
                EditText Number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                EditText Key = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText Message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
                this.number=Number.getText().toString();
                this.key=Key.getText().toString();
                this.message=Message.getText().toString();

                if ((this.key.length()<4)|(this.key.length()>32)){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(acran2.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Вы вели не правильное число символов")
                            .setMessage("проверте количество символов ключа для шифрования")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("ОК",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }

               Log.i(TAG,"номер телефона равен"+" "+number);
               Log.i(TAG, "ключ равен"+" "+key);
               Log.i(TAG, "сообщение"+" "+message);
                break;
            case (R.id.imageButton):
                break;
            default: break;
        }
//        button4();

    }
```

---

```
public class Obrabothic_Klucha {
    final static Logger log =Logger.getLogger(Obrabothic_Klucha.class.getName());
    private static final String TAG="myLogs";
    acran2 acran2=new acran2();

    public List<Integer> list=new ArrayList();

    public int Perevod_16_2 () {
        try {
//            acran2.button4();
            String massiv_kluch[]=new String[acran2.key.length()];
            int a;
            for (int p=0; p<acran2.key.length();p++){
                massiv_kluch[p]= String.valueOf(acran2.key.charAt(p));
                a=Integer.parseInt(massiv_kluch[p], 16);
                list.add(Integer.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(a)));
            }

            String aaa="";
            for (int p=0; p<list.size();p++){
                aaa=aaa+this.list.get(p)+" ";
            }

            Log.i(TAG,"ключ в двоичном виде:"+" "+aaa);}
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.i(TAG,"ключ неверен:");
            return Perevod_16_2();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: что за "Java класс" из которого нужно вернуть значение? Создается его экземпляр? как вызываете обработку? вызванный метод не возвращает ничего? приложите код, будет легче вам помочь

Comment: что мешает вам создать экземпляр этого класса , через  аргумент метода передать нужный параметр и вернуть нужное вам значение этим методом?

Comment: ничего не мешает)....что-то тупанул, даже стыдно)

Comment: Так же Вам желательно почитать конвеншены по офрмлению кода... Названия классов с заглавной буквы и без нижнего подчеркивания.)